# Will moving a WordPress from one location to another result in broken links

Tags: seo, wordpress, links, 404, migration

I am having a WordPress installed at `www.mydomain.com/blog/wordpress/`
I am planning to move it to `www.mydomain.com/blog/`

**Will this cause any 404 broken links?** This question may seem stupid but please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

You just rename the blog address in settings and all will work fine.